# How did Trafalgar Law get to and leave Marineford?

Tags: one-piece

My question is two-fold:

1. How did Trafalgar Law and the other "Worst Generation" pirates get to Marineford? I thought you had to go through the tri-currents? Or is that the tri-currents are just a faster way but you can come any other way since Marineford is not in the calm belt?
2. How did Trafalgar Law leave the tri-currents? This especially puzzled me. I am thinking now that it might be because of their submarine. My assumption is that it can move freely, does not depend on currents, but I am not sure.

I would appreciate answers that are based on more than just speculation.

Answer (score 1):

So, to add a bit of clarification to all the answers.

The **Tri-current** (Tarai Current) are a natural whirlpool at the intersection of the Calm Belt and Red Line. The WG build three facilities around the current (*Impel Down - MarineFord - Enies Lobby*), making use of the current power to fast travel between the three. The **currents work also underwater** as per natural ocean currents, but probably have different speeds and power at different underwater levels.

Here's a pictures depicting the wihrlpool:

[image]

The *Gates of Justice* are 3 such gates placed at the "corners" of the current from where you can enter or access it. This is the only way for normal ships (floating ships) to get inside the current. The whole phenomenon doesn't quite follow natural physics so one shouldn't try to find natural ways of how to enter/exit it.

Also, you can't get in from the outside without using the gates as the outside currents will push you away from the whirlpool and vice-versa from the inside where the whirlpool will keep pushing you into a circle.

**Now on how Law & others managed to get there.**

One possibility is that they entered the current by going underwater through the Gates of Justice **while they were openend**. After the gates close, the outside currents will keep you from entering, even underwater. That is why Bepo said to hurry as the gates are closing, so they could catch the overflowing current to the outside, while submerged. The same applies to WB's ship who was also underwater.

Another possibility for WB's ship to enter is if he used the *Gura Gura no Mi*'s powers to temporarily divert the currents and enter from any side of the whirlpool. Law still had to enter from the gates nontheless.

And even another posibility could be that they entered MarineFord by bypassing the big current, from Sabaody Arch. for exemple, and managed to get around the marines defence of those waters. They probably left through the Gate of Justice to make for a quick escape rather then going back and risking to get captured.

More on [One Piece fandom](https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/Tarai_Current) about the Tarai Current.

Comment: I am not sure why you are saying Law had to enter from the gates. In your depiction even, we can see that there seems to be other ways to arrive there by just sailing. And this does not explain 2 at all.

Comment: @Akaisteph7 I guess you refer to the fact that Law could bypass the currents and get to MarineFord directly. As per the image above it is possible, I doubt the Marines have left those waters unprotected. There are probably many layers of defence around the 3 facilities and one can't go unnotice around there so you have to use the currents somehow. Even with a submarine, remember that BigMom had underwater snails that detected movement. These are just my asumptions based on all the info there is about the Tarai Currents.

Comment: @Akaisteph7 I've edited my answer to cover that possibility aswell :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Ya they took the current because they wouldn't have made it in time otherwise, there's no indication that you can't get there any other way.
2. Considering white beard's entire fleet got there underwater I assume that you're able to maneuver freely.

Answer (score 0):

Tri Currents has nothing to do with getting to and leaving Marine Ford. It only helps if you are trying to go to and fro from Ennis Lobby, Impel Down or Marine Ford. It does not mean that this is the only way to get to Marine Ford. It is just one of the way.

Tri currents is a marine exclusive current between Impel Down, Ennis Lobby and Marine Ford. Using this way will increase the speed of travel between these places.

You can get to Marine Ford from Sabaody archipelago in half an hour without using the currents. Marines and Celestial Dragons travel regularly between the two.

Only problems for Pirates and other criminals to use this way would be the heavy patrols. But they can get past these patrols by doing what WB, Law did and come underwater. Or by doing what Luffy did(when he rang the Ox Bell) by hijacking a marine ship, you can get there.

Since Law never entered the currents, he never had to leave it.

On a side note, Luffy, Jinbei, Crocodile, and Co would have been trapped the Tri Currents if not for Black Beard, when they escaped Impel Down through the Tri Currents.

Comment: Tri-currents obviously has to do with getting to and from Marineford... It might not be the only way though, which I am guessing you're trying to say. That answers 1. But Law obviously entered the currents to leave Marineford, maybe you should check what actually happened before making such claims. This is why I said I wanted more than just speculation.

Comment: Where did he enter tri currents? He just went underwater and escaped. Exactly when did Law enter the Tri Currents?

Comment: Before they leave, I think Bepo says to hurry because the gates of justice are about to close. They don't actually show them entering the currents but why would they mention that if they don't pass through the gates?.. It's in Chapter 580.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I did not see that part. I don't know Law used the Tri Currents.

Comment: I don't know the exact answer as to how he got out. But one way could be that he got under the currents since it was a submarmine and got out.

Or since Hancock was following them, she could have asked the marines to open the gate when they reached Ennis Lobby or Impel Down.

Comment: I am thinking it has something to do with the submarine but I am not sure, hence the question. And also, you should not be able to leave the tricurrents that easily. Maybe they depended on Boa Hancock somehow.. I would love some clarity on this.

Comment: @Akaisteph7 Flipping through Ch580 and the few chapters surrounding it Bepo doesn't seem to mention the gates of justice could you cite a more specific page? In Ch 580 Bepo warns Law that gawking at the carnage is a bad idea given their dire circumstances but doesn't seem to mention the Gates of Justice. It simply doesn't make sense to make use of the tub currents as Bepo is surprised Hancock even found them so they wouldn't have had a way out at ether Enies Lobby or Impel Down. The simplest assumption is that everybody left via not the tub currents

Comment: @Gatchwar Interesting, I can't find it either. But I also don't remember which site I was reading from. I'm starting to think it might have just been a wrong translation then..

Comment: @Akaisteph7 Possibly, do note that we do not know how far down the gates of justice extend, I don't think its brought up and they wouldn't need to extend deeper than sea level if you're just trying to stop sailing ships. Law's submarine is pretty unique in that regard. We also know from the trip to Fish Man Island that currents may begin and end at different depths so maybe they could just go under the gates and the currents but that isn't touched on since it is never said how they leave. It seems to be more logical they leave how everyone else does, perhaps consider editing the question?

Answer (score 0):

The Heart Pirates (Law’s crew) travel by submarine, rather than normal ship. Using their sub, they were either able to pass below the Gates of Justice (this is my presumption) or travel under/around the currents normally blocking passage to Marineford.

They left the same way, staying a fair distance from the actual island and fighting. Kizaru attempted to stop them, firing beams into the ocean as they dove, but the sub made it out of the area (we can assume they left the same way they entered).